# Active Record .where.find_each

Tags: ruby, activerecord, batch-processing

I am trying batch processing from [Example here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each).

```
Course.where( "blocks != nil" && "blocks.size > 0").find_each do |course|
#logic on course variable
end
```

I get this error:

> `method_missing': undefined method`find_each' for # (NoMethodError)

(`blocks` is an attribute which is of type array of course model)
I checked that where returns an array of results, so shouldn't there be a batch processing find_each on the resulting array? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you include the full definition of your `Course` class?

Comment: should it be like this `Course.find_each(conditions: 'blocks is not null and size > 0')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Course.where('blocks IS NOT NULL AND length(blocks) > 0').find_each do |course|
    #logic on course variable
  end
```